# Why is there a difference between the width of a textarea and a plain div's border?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a simple html div with only its borders which expands and shrinks together with a textarea.
I managed to code the needed js in order to do it,but i always get a small gap* around 2-3 pixels between the 2 elements,at their default position as well when they expand.
Any ideas how to fix it ?

*It seems there is no gap in the snippet but there is gap when i try it in chrome,FF and edge.

**proof** :

[image]

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="small-box"></div>
  <textarea id="textarea" onmousemove="resizeBoxWidth()"></textarea>
  <style>
    #small-box {
      font-size: 30;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 3.5;
      top: 40px;
      left: 40px;
      width: 450px;
      height: 100px;
      border-color: black;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 3px;
      position: absolute;
    }
    
    #textarea {
      min-height: 100px;
      max-height: 100px;
      border-width: 3px;
      border-color: black;
      top: 150px;
      left: 40px;
      width: 450px;
      height: 100px;
      position: absolute;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    function resizeBoxWidth() {
      var smallBox = document.getElementById("small-box");

      var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");

      smallBox.style.width = textarea.style.width;

    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You forgot to add the size unit. So try adding:

`border-width: 3px;`

Comment: This could be a difference in the default `box-sizing` setting between elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to `box-sizing`, which defines how `width` is calculated, [to quote MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing):

> By default in the CSS box model, the width and height you assign to an element is applied only to the element's content box. If the element has any border or padding, this is then added to the width and height to arrive at the size of the box that's rendered on the screen.

If you give each element the same `box-sizing` setting, the size will be calculated in the same way and appear the same size.

```js
function resizeBoxWidth() {
  var smallBox = document.getElementById("small-box");
  var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");
  smallBox.style.width = textarea.style.width;
}
```

```css
#small-box {
  font-size: 30;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 3.5;
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;
  width: 450px;
  height: 100px;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#textarea {
  min-height: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: black;
  top: 150px;
  left: 40px;
  width: 450px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="small-box"></div>
<textarea id="textarea" onmousemove="resizeBoxWidth()"></textarea>
```

Comment: You got ahead of me :))

Comment: THIS. 
I gave them both the - box-sizing: border-box; - property and they came to the same size.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

By short view using the inspect tool I have found that the default of textarea contains `padding: 2px;` which affects the position and width of the textarea.

Unlike the div that don't contain any pervious attributes.

[Inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJjw0.png)